# Calculate standard deviation for groups of values using Python

Tags: python, pandas-groupby, aggregate, standard-deviation

My data looks similar to this:

```
index name number difference
0     AAA  10     0
1     AAA  20     10
2     BBB  1      0
3     BBB  2      1
4     CCC  5      0
5     CCC  10     5
6     CCC  10.5   0.5
```

I need to calculate standard deviation for difference column based on groups of name.

I tried

```
data[['difference']].groupby(['name']).agg(['mean', 'std'])
```

and

```
data["std"]=(data['difference'].groupby('name').std())
```

but both gave KeyError for the variable that's passed to `groupby()`. I tried to resolve it with:

```
data.columns = data.columns.str.strip()
```

but the error persists.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are trying to run a groupby on a single column. 'name' doesn't exist in ```data[['difference']]```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupby(['name'])` on the full data frame first, and only apply the agg on the columns of interest:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'name':['AAA','AAA','BBB','BBB','CCC','CCC','CCC'],
                    'number':[10,20,1,2,5,10,10.5],
                    'difference':[0,10,0,1,0,5,0.5]})
data.groupby(['name'])['difference'].agg(['mean', 'std'])
```

Comment: I think this worked. Thank you.